# Cannot create S3 Bucket on another region after deleting on the other

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I had S3 bucket created on Region1 and then we decided to use Region2 so what I did is just deleted the bucket and tried to create it (with the same name) on that Region2.

But it keep throwing

`A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource. Please try again.`

Probably I have to wait but not sure how much (waited about 15 minutes)

Comment: it's not SDK, it's all from console

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bucket names must be unique across entire S3 so you have to wait until your deleted bucket name becomes available for reuse.

References:

> The bucket name you choose must be unique across all existing bucket
>   names in Amazon S3

(Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/CreatingABucket.html)

> When you delete a bucket, there may be a delay of up to one hour
>   before the bucket name is available for reuse in a new region or by a
>   new bucket owner

(Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/DeletingAnObjectandBucket.html)

Comment: Wow. I was wondering why this works and tried to go through the entire S3 documentation. Thank you.